# Через раз работает условный переход в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Условие: если, (х1 + х4)%3 == х3, то х2 = 5, иначе х3, х4 = х4, х3
При некоторых вводных, условие исполняется верно(например 1 0 1 3 или 1 3 2 4), а при других исполняется ветка иначе (1 0 2 1 или 1 2 1 1 или 1 0 0 5). Не понимаю в чем именно ошибка

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    char x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4;
    printf("Введите набор значений x1, x2, x3, x4\n");
    scanf("%c %c %c %c", &x1, &x2, &x3, &x4);
    //printf("%c %c %c %c", y1, y2, y3, y4);
    if ((isdigit(x1)) && (isdigit(x2)) && (isdigit(x3)) && (isdigit(x4)))
    {

asm (
 ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
 "mov al, %7     ;"//переносим из x4
 "mov %3, al     ;"// в y4

 "mov al, %6     ;"//переносим из х3
 "mov %2, al     ;"//в у3

 "mov al, %5     ;"//переносим из х2
 "mov %1, al     ;"//в у2

 "mov al, %4     ;"//переносим из х1
 "mov %0, al     ;"//в у1

 "mov cl, %7    ;"//сохраняем в ah x4
 "mov al, %4    ;"// а в al первый
 "add al, cl    ;"
 "cbw           ;"
 "mov bl, '3'   ;"
 "div bl        ;"
 "mov cl, ah    ;"
 "cmp cl, %6    ;"//сравниваем их
 "jz ELSE       ;"//если == остаток, то переходим на ELSE
 "mov al, %6    ;"
 "mov cl, %7    ;"
 "mov %3, al    ;"
 "mov %2, cl    ;"
 "jmp EXIT      ;" //безусловный переход на выход
 "ELSE:         ;"
 "mov %1, '5'   ;"
 "jmp EXIT      ;"
 "EXIT :        ;"


 ".att_syntax   ;"
 :"=&r"(y1), "=&r"(y2), "=&r"(y3), "=&r"(y4)
 :"r"(x1), "r"(x2), "r" (x3), "r" (x4)
 : "ax", "bx", "cx", "dx"

);
    printf("полученная строка\n");
    printf("%c %c %c %c", y1, y2, y3, y4);
    return 0;
    }
    else {printf("Error\n");}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот эта строка вызывает сомнение.

```
"mov bl, '3'   ;"
```

С ассемблером я давно работал, но все же мне кажется, что здесь в регистр bl заносится не число 3, а символ '3' - а по факту код этого символа.

Comment: Да там же везде коды символов, соответственно для ввода 1 0 1 3 получается верное равенство (49+51)%51 == 49, для 1 3 2 4 — (49+52)%51 == 48, а для 1 0 2 1 — (49+49)%51 != 50